# How can I display shaded pages?

Tags: support, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-edge

I dropped a pen on my keyboard, and it made the displayed post to show some cool shaded borders:

[image: cool image]

I refreshed the page, and it went back to normal:

[image: boring image]

What did I accidentally press?

I am using Microsoft Edge Version 121.0.2277.112.

Comment: That's simply "selected" by keyboard navigation.

Comment: What are these? Screenshots for ants?